# Is there a GeneXus Server for Support tickets?

Tags: genexus

Is there a GeneXus Server that both GeneXus Support and the GeneXus Customer can use to collaborate on ticket cases?  I know we can easily deploy a simple KB (with some test case) to the Cloud and anyone can run it, but is there a way for GeneXus Support to have access to that same KB through a GXS?

This could be helping in getting to a resolution quicker.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Open or Sandbox GeneXus Server](https://gxserver.com/en/plans/public-gxserver).